# Is there a way of adapting this function so it doesn't use LINQ? (convert byte array to string)

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a way I can alter this function which converts byte arrays to a string so it doesn't use LINQ? (to make it compatible with prior .NET versions)?

```
private string ByteToString(byte[] data)
{
    return String.Concat(data.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

Most methods found on the web, seem to return an unprintable unicode string. The code above above returns a safe string (eg b8b30dcfcac41ebd5313107adf7054024fb1ac69 rather than loads of high-ASCII chars) however I don't really understand what the function above is doing (especially with regards to the "x2" parameter.

Comment: Here is a reference to what the "x2" is doing: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: x2 will return 2-hex-digit string interpretation of a number. So if b=10 b.ToString return 0a. X2 would return 0A (capital A).

Comment: Why don't you want to use LINQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, you can just roll it into a `foreach` loop if all you want to do is make the code above "non-LINQ".  `String.Concat()` just concatenates an `IEnumerable` into a string, which we can do with a `StringBuilder`:

```
private string ByteToString(byte[] data)
{
    var builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (int i=0; i<data.Length; i++)
    {
        builder.Append(data[i].ToString("x2"));
    }

    return builder.ToString();
}
```

Probably many ways to do this, but this would be a fairly literal translation of the LINQ code you list.

Answer (score 0):

```
private string ByteToString(byte[] data)
{
    return BitConverter.ToString(data).Replace("-", "").ToLowerInvariant();
}
```

BTW, you *can* use Linq to Objects when you target .NET 2, thanks to [LinqBridge](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/linqbridge.aspx) (you still need VS2008 of course)

Comment: With the caveat that the `.Replace` call is probably going to hurt performance. Readability might trump that, though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looing for:

```
  string s = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

And the other way around:

```
  byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(s);
```

Comment: It looks like he wants the hex representation of the bytes, so this is probably not what he's looking for.

Comment: Roger's correct - that produces an unreadable string. I didn't phrase my question very well as I wasn't sure exactly what the function was doing but as Roger says, I need hex bytes as a string.

Answer (score 0):

First you just need to convert your bytes to something more useful, like UTF8 for example, and then you can get you string from it.
Something like (in my case: iso-8859-1):

```
    buf = Encoding.Convert(Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1"), Encoding.UTF8, buf);
    tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way I can alter this function which converts byte arrays to
>   a string so it doesn't use LINQ? (to make it compatible with prior
>   .NET versions)?

Assuming you can still use C# 3 or later, you can do:

```
 return string.Concat(Array.ConvertAll(data, b => b.ToString("x2")));
```

> however I don't really understand what the function above is doing
>   (especially with regards to the "x2" parameter.

It's converting each byte to a hexadecimal representation (two characters), and then concatenating all those characters into a single string. See The Hexadecimal ("X") Format Specifier in [Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#XFormatString).

Comment: But that still uses LINQ operators (=>) so won't work in .NET 2.0

Comment: @Nick G: That's not a "LINQ" operator, that's the ["goes to" operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311046.aspx) - part of a lambda expression. It's not tied to LINQ in any way, only to C# 3 or later. You can still use them in C# projects and target .NET 2.0, as long as you use a newish compiler.

Answer (score -1):

```
private string ByteToString(byte[] data)
{
    return String.Concat(data.Select(b => b.ToString("x2")));
}
```

**"x2"** parameter is applied to **byte**'s class function **ToString()**, applied for each instance, with requirement of output **2**(2), **hexadecimal**(x), lowercase characters.

That is what is going beneath the select query, it takes the string representation of bytes and concats all of them to the resulting string as a return argument of a function call.

Did I answer your question?

I do not see nothing wrong with using LINQ queries.

Comment: LINQ isn't available in earlier versions of .NET

Comment: @ChrisF: Keep your grapes close, man, I'm on a .NET 4.5, and, currently, from Windows Developer Preview, and LINQ IS available at least for the version FW 4.0, so question did not include exact FW version to compile against, so don't cock your votes

Comment: It was quite obvious that I meant versions of .NET where LINQ is unavailable. Ie, 2.0 and below.